# How do I assign 1 image to each color channel as input to ResNet50

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, regression, resnet

I am trying to build a ResNet50 model that performs regression to a single output and takes an input of 3 images. All 3 images are the same size (brain scans of 160*160) and I want to assign each image to a color channel (first image to Red, second to Green, and third to Blue, as all 3 images are black and white.), in order to avoid building a new network. I have already build a regressor with ResNet50 which accepts 1 image as input. Here is my code:

```
def load_train(path):
    
    """
    It loads the train part of dataset from path
    """
    #1 / 255
    labels = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\sumad\\OneDrive - San José Unified School District\\Documents\\AMYLOID DATASET COMPLETE ALL\\Full Set\\AllAmyloidREFNORMTarget.csv')
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2, rescale=None)
    train_gen_flow = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=labels,
        directory='C:\\Users\\sumad\OneDrive - San José Unified School District\\Documents\\AMYLOID DATASET COMPLETE ALL\\Full Set\\AllAmyloidOneImagePNG\\',
        x_col='ID',
        y_col='Value',
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='raw',
        subset = 'training',
        seed=12345)

    return train_gen_flow


def load_test(path):
    
    """
    It loads the validation/test part of dataset from path
    """
    labels = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\sumad\\OneDrive - San José Unified School District\\Documents\\AMYLOID DATASET COMPLETE ALL\\Full Set\\AllAmyloidREFNORMTarget.csv')
    validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2, rescale=None)
    test_gen_flow = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe = labels,
    directory='C:\\Users\\sumad\OneDrive - San José Unified School District\\Documents\\AMYLOID DATASET COMPLETE ALL\\Full Set\\AllAmyloidOneImagePNG\\',
    x_col="ID",
    y_col="Value", 
    class_mode="raw", 
    target_size=(224,224), 
    batch_size=32,
    subset = "validation",
    seed=1234,
    )

    return test_gen_flow


def create_model(input_shape):
    
    # we will use ResNet50 architecture, with freezing top layers
    backbone = ResNet50(input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(backbone)
    
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0003)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae', metrics=['mae'])
    print(model.summary())

    return model

def train_model(model, train_data, test_data, batch_size=32, epochs=100,
                steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None):

    history = model.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data, batch_size=batch_size, 
              epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
              validation_steps=validation_steps, verbose=2)

    # Get training and test loss histories
    training_loss = history.history['loss']
    test_loss = history.history['val_loss']

    epoch_count = range(1, len(training_loss) + 1)

    plt.plot(epoch_count, training_loss, 'r--')
    plt.plot(epoch_count, test_loss, 'b-')
    plt.legend(['Training Loss', 'Test Loss'])
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.show();

    return model

def main():

    path = 'C:\\Users\\sumad\\OneDrive - San José Unified School        District\\Documents\\AMYLOID DATASET COMPLETE ALL\\Full Set\\'

    train_data = load_train(path)
    test_data = load_test(path)

    model = create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3))

model = train_model(model, train_data, test_data)
```

Comment: You need to load the data yourself to stack three images as channels. How long is your dataset? If it fits in memory, it is easier to load all of them at once and then feed your network with loaded data. Can you provide more on where is your data, its format and how is stored?

Comment: Yes there are about 3000 test cases each with 3 (or 1) images each. Each test case has a folder who’s folder name corresponds to a name in a data frame with the value next to it. In each folder is 3 images, each a 160 by 160 PNG.

Comment: And which of those three images do you want to map to each channel?

Comment: They are each a slice of a brain scan, I would like to map the first image, slice 1, to Red, the second, slice 2, to Green, and the third, slice 3, to Blue

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using keras, I assume you have also Pillow installed.

This code snippet stacks three images, read as grayscale, into a single one as RGB. Then what you need is to call this method for each example to generate a list of RGB-like images and its labels, but for this poin I'ld need more information on your specific settings, and as I see it, is out of scope for this question.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def load_images_to_single(path_a, path_b, path_c, size=(224, 224):

    # load images as grayscale
    img_a = np.array(Image.open(path_a).convert('L').resize(size))
    img_b = np.array(Image.open(path_b).convert('L').resize(size))
    img_c = np.array(Image.open(path_c).convert('L').resize(size))

    # map images to channels as:
    #     img_a -> R channel
    #     img_b -> G channel
    #     img_c -> B channel
    img_rgb = np.dstack([img_a, img_b, img_c])

    return img_rgb
```

The all you need to do is, first, iterate over the dataset to build your `X_train, y_train` and the same for test, since this beheaviour is a little different from default.

It will only work is your data fits into memory, otherwise you need to implement your own [`DataGeneration`](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly).